# TypeScript creating global Variables and Methods

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript...
I have some external js files (have to keep them and work with them)

So in TypeScript I am trying to create a GlobalVariables object and GlobalMethods object that maps to the external js files vars and functions. I have the GlobalVariables object working, not the GlobalMethods object. Code below...

The STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE property that's commented out is the part not working...

```
declare function HelloWorld(): string;
declare var siteRoot: string;
declare function StatusMessageResponse(msg: any, callBackFunction: string): void;

export const GlobalVariables = Object.freeze({
    BASE_API_URL: 'http://example.com/',
    SITE_ROOT: siteRoot,
});

export const GlobalMethods = Object.freeze({
    HELLO_WORD: HelloWorld(),
    //STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE(msg: any, callBackFunction: string): StatusMessageResponse(msg: any, callBackFunction: string): void,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
export const GlobalMethods = Object.freeze({
    HELLO_WORD: HelloWorld,
    STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE: StatusMessageResponse
});
```

When assigning (using `=`) you must pass a value not a type.
If you want to specify a type then:

```
export const GlobalMethods: {
    HELLO_WORD: () => string;
    STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE: (msg: any, callBackFunction: string) => void
} = Object.freeze({
    HELLO_WORD: HelloWorld,
    STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE: StatusMessageResponse
});
```

---

#### Edit

Let's start with the simple assignment:

```
export const GlobalMethods = Object.freeze({
    HELLO_WORD: HelloWorld,
    STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE: StatusMessageResponse
});
```

This is all javascript, the object that is being passed to `Object.freeze` is a simple object containing two properties: `HELLO_WORD` and `STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE` and they reference two functions that you've declared that are present in the global scope.

To spice things up we can annotate it with types.
There are several ways to accomplish that, all of these are equivalent:

```
export const GlobalMethods: {
    HELLO_WORD: () => string;
    STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE: (msg: any, callBackFunction: string) => void
} = Object.freeze({ ... });
```

Using an interface:

```
interface MyFunctions {
    HELLO_WORD: () => string;
    STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE: (msg: any, callBackFunction: string) => void
}
export const GlobalMethods: MyFunctions = Object.freeze({ ... });
```

Using type alias:

```
type MyFunctions = {
    HELLO_WORD: () => string;
    STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE: (msg: any, callBackFunction: string) => void
}
export const GlobalMethods: MyFunctions = Object.freeze({ ... });
```

You can also type assert instead of declaring the type for the variable:

```
export const GlobalMethods = Object.freeze({ ... }) as MyFunctions;
```

All of the above declare a type that contains two properties of function types with specific signatures:

- `HELLO_WORD` is a function with no args which returns a string: `() => string`
- `STATUS_MESSAGE_RESPONSE` is a function with two args `msg` of type `any` and `callBackFunction` of type string (probably a mistake?) and the function doesn't return.

Comment: Hey mate, it looks like what you have is correct. But can you explain it to me a little more? I'm a newbie to TypeScript... Also, the HELLO_WORD returns the function structure, not the string? It returns, function HelloWorld() { return "Hello World!"; }
.

Comment: Check my revised answer. Hopefully I managed to clear things for you

Comment: Thanks! But, still why doesn't HELLO_WORD return the string "Hello World!"? Instead it returns the function structure?

Comment: Because it has a reference to the function object. I haven't noticed that in your code you're doing `HELLO_WORD: HelloWorld()`, I have it as `HELLO_WORD: HelloWorld` (notice that my version doesn't end with `()`)

Comment: I guess it does return the string, just not in console.log()... Thanks again mate.

Comment: It returns the function object, you need to invoke it to get the string: `GlobalMethods.HELLO_WORD()`